# Differentiating symlink files from symlink directories when using scandir

Tags: symlink, scandir

I've been using `scandir`, and differentiating between directories and files using d_type:

```
int isdir(const struct dirent *entry)
{
return entry->d_name[0]!='.' && entry->d_type&4;
}
```

and

```
int isfile(const struct dirent *entry)
{
return entry->d_name[0]!='.' && entry->d_type&8;
}
```

It's abundantly clear that `0100b` is a directory, and `1000b` is a file, and after a bit of sleuthing it became obvious to me that `0010b` represents a symbolic link. So you'd think (or at least, I did) that `0110b` would represent a symlink directory, and that `1010b` would be a symlink to a file, but that's not what I'm experiencing.

Instead, all symlinks are showing a `d_type` of `1010b` be they regular file or directory. How can I differentiate a symlink file from a symlink directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "symlink file" or "symlink directory".  A symlink is its own type: it's the same kind of object no matter what it points to. Also, it need not even point to anything: a symlink can be broken. Look at the `stat` system call, and compare with `lstat`.  `stat` reads through a symlink; `lstat` gets the properties of a symlink inode itself.

Comment: Thanks, I read your answer some hours ago and have been reading/experimenting about/with `stat` ever since. I get the idea, but I'm a bit stuck as to how to use it. The problem is that although scandir() knows the full path, it's not supplying that to isdir(), and S_ISDIR requires the full path to operate. I'm getting errno==2 using the filename alone as it exists in entry->d_name. I shall persevere.